# How to get started on building my own jekyll template?

Tags: github, jekyll, liquid, jekyll-extensions

How do I make my own design in jekyll blog ? Currently I have the default `minima` theme I got by `jekyll new my-blog` and no idea of how to get started on designing my own `posts`, `main` etc layouts. For some reason I don't see the typical `_layouts` and `_includes` folders when I ran the `jekyll new` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't see the typical `_layouts` and `_includes` folders when I ran the Jekyll new command

Then start by creating them. They are just folders. You can start a layout with this minimal structure in a file `_layouts/main.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ content }}
  </body>
</html>
```

With an "hello world" be like this:

```
---
layout: main
---
Hello World
```

Then extend the layout with whatever you want, like a normal web page: css, header, footer, ...